# onAfterSetHTML doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dom-events, fckeditor

The event `onAfterSetHTML`, present in FCKeditor, does not work for CKEDITOR. Is there any replacement for this event in the newer version? Also, where can I get a list of available events for CKEDITOR?

Answer (score 0):

There are many classes which fire events, so there's no single events list. But you can in general find them in the [API docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api).

I guess that the one which you're looking for is [`editor#dataReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-dataReady).

Comment: Is this an event that's fired after the setData() method?